# Finding two complex conjugate roots from a cubic equation

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

Given the following cubic equation

$\lambda^3+(  \sigma+b+1)\lambda^2+(r+\sigma)b\lambda+2\sigma b(r-1)=0$

And given the fact that $\sigma=10$ and $b=\frac{8}{3}$

Suppose that that there are $3$ roots to the following equation $\lambda_{1}$,$\lambda_{2}$ and $\lambda_{3}$, and suppose that for some unknown values of $r$ ($r$ is to be taken as always greater than $1$) we have all $3$ roots that are real and negative and  as we increase the value of $r$ to above the certain critical value, call this value $r*$, the three root changes to become one real and two complex conjguate roots with the real part of the complex conjugate being negative. Find this critical value of $r*$ in which the complex conjugate roots start to appear.

For a quadratic equation, it is simple I just need the quadratic formula and study how the roots behave, but im unsure how to do it if the equation is in cubic form. What I think of doing is to write the cubic equation in this form $(\lambda-\lambda_{1}$)($\lambda-\lambda_{2}$)($\lambda-\lambda_{3}$) and then expanding out the terms and then comparing it with the original expression. Could anyone explain how to do this. Thanks

Comment: what is $r$ here?

Comment: $r$ is taken to be always greater than $1$

Comment: `Find this critical value of r∗` Hint: that will be when the equation has a double (real) root.

Comment: I know that multiplying out two complex conjugate root will give a real root and together with the original real root this gives a double real root.

Comment: Double real root means transforming the cubic equation to a quadratic one?

Comment: @yswong The double root (which will turn out to be real) must be a common root of the cubic and its derivative. The condition for such a common root to exist will give `r∗`.

Comment: So i find the derivative and then i find the condition at which the roots of the derivative have a double root?

Comment: @yswong No, you find the condition for (at least) one of the roots of the derivative to also satisfy the cubic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) of the polynomial. For a cubic polynomial with real coefficients, it is positive if the roots are three distinct real numbers, and negative if there is one real root and two complex conjugate roots.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the response. Is there other ways of working out the question from first principle without having to memorize what the discriminant was.

Comment: The discriminant is zero if and only if there is a double root. ys song's comments give another way of finding $r^*$.